# How does Python matplotlib treat binary data?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use matplotlib to plot binary data read from a file:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

try:
    f = open(file, 'rb')
    data = f.read(100)
    plt.plot(data)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    f.close()
```

But I got the following error:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The file I'm reading consists of binary data. So how does matplotlib treat binary data? Is it unsigned or signed 1 byte data?

Comment: How do you expect `matplotlib` to interpret random binary data? What sort of plot are you looking for?

Comment: If it was saved in a way you know, you can try to load it using the [`np.memmap` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html).

Comment: @MattDMo: I'm looking for a line plot given the binary data read in.

Comment: @askewchan: I just want to use plot to see what it looks like. Does plot require ASCII data format instead of binary?

Comment: The issue here has nothing to do with plotting, it's just about trying to read binary data as values in python.

Comment: Try `print`ing your data instead of plotting it if you want to see what I mean.

Comment: @askewchan If I print <code>data</code>, it prints as <code>b'\xfd\xd0\xfb\xcaM......</code>. So I need a parser to parse binary data to ASCII data format for plot function, right?

Comment: @tonga Binary data can be stored in a million different ways (actually a lot more :)). For example, you might have 4-byte long integer values in that binary file, or you might have 64-bit floating point values, or you might have a bzipped-text file, etc. etc. You need to first find out how data is organized in the binary data file. Post this information as part of this question. The answer will probably be obvious at that stage.

Comment: Also, if you know the type/format of data that is stored in the binary file, you can use [`numpy.fromfile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) to read it into an array.

Comment: @crayzeewulf Thanks for your information. I actually don't have the information about how the binary data is formatted in that file. I just want to see if plot in matplotlib can directly treat binary data as signed or unsigned char like in C and plot them as if those 100 bytes can be 100 chars or uchars.

Comment: @tonga - As crazeewulf already pointed out, `numpy.fromfile` is quite handy for what you're describing (There's also `numpy.fromstring` and `frombuffer`, if the data isn't in a file).  If you want unsigned chars, then do `data = numpy.fromfile(yourfile, dtype=numpy.uint8)`, if you want signed chars, then do `data = numpy.fromfile(yourfile, dtype=numpy.int8)`.   If you don't want to use numpy have a look at the builtin `struct` or `array` modules.  Either way, if you want `uint`s, you need to convert the string to a sequence of `uint`s. Hopefully that helps clarify things a touch.

Answer (score 5):

As has been pointed out in the comments of your question, the bytes you are passing to plot are ambiguous. You need to turn those bytes into a numpy array (or a list/tuple) before passing it to matplotlib.

A simple example to demonstrate this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


orig_array = np.arange(10, dtype=np.uint8)
with open('my_binary_data.dat', 'wb') as write_fh:
    write_fh.write(orig_array)

with open('my_binary_data.dat', 'rb') as fh:
    loaded_array = np.frombuffer(fh.read(), dtype=np.uint8)

print loaded_array
plt.plot(loaded_array)
plt.show()
```

I've gone around the houses in demonstrating using numpy.frombuffer with the bytes you read into your "data" variable, but in truth you would just use numpy.fromfile so that the loading line looks like:

```
loaded_array = np.fromfile(fh, dtype=np.uint8)
```

HTH